# Why is Python throwing a NameError when doing nested exceptions with same variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

I ran into a case with nested `try`/`except` statements where I do not understand the behaviour of the Python interpreter.

An equivalent example to my usecase (connection errors) is in the minimal, reproducible example below:

```py
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as error:
    try:
        [1, 2, 3][3]
    except IndexError as error:
        pass
    print("The last error was:", error)
```

This example has the following output

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sorenmulli/lala.py", line 2, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sorenmulli/lala.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("The last error was:", error)
NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

where I would expect it to to output

```
The last error was: list index out of range.
```

I can get the expected behaviour by changing the code to

```py
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as error_tmp:
    error = error_tmp
    try:
        [1, 2, 3][3]
    except IndexError as error_tmp:
        error = error_tmp
    print("The last error was:", error)
```

but this looks strange in my opinion: Why is this necessary? Shouldn't the second assignment to `error` either overwrite the first or not: Why does it delete the variable completely?

- I am using Python 3.9.16, but I think the output is consistent across Python 3 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is  [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

> When an exception has been assigned using `as` target, it is cleared at
> the end of the `except` clause. This is as if

```
except E as N:
    foo
```

> was translated to

```
except E as N:
    try:
        foo
    finally:
        del N
```

> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be
> able to refer to it after the `except` clause. Exceptions are cleared
> because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference
> cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive
> until the next garbage collection occurs.

So in your code the `error` will be cleared at the end of `except IndexError as error` block.

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as error:
    try:
        [1, 2, 3][3]
    except IndexError as error:
        pass # `error` will be cleared here
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation: I was not aware of the deletion of the variable and that it was documented.

I still feel like this is confusing from a users point of view. I found [another, similar example](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84905) where some Python developers argued that it was not inconsistent.

I guess that the reason is the implementation detail in the fact that exceptions form a "reference cycle with the stack frame", which I do not quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the second assignment to error either overwrite the first or not: Why does it delete the variable completely?

Yes, the `error` variable is getting overwritten in the inner try-except block and after which it is deleted once we are out of the inner block.

Here Python is just following the simple rule of de-referencing the variables outside the scope of the try-except block, however it affects the outer block as well because the variable was same.

Try running this code, you will see 2 different ID for the `error` variable. One ID when in the first try-except block and the other ID for the inside try-except block.

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as error:
    print("ID 1: ", id(error))
    try:
        [1, 2, 3][3]
    except IndexError as error:
        print("ID 2: ", id(error))
        pass
    print("The last error was:", error)
```

And the other thing is your print statement fall outside the inner try-except block, so until Python Interpreter reached that `print("The last error was:", error)` line the inner try-except block has already finished and hence the `error` variable was deleted and the NameError exception.

In the second code you described, it worked because you were copying the reference to the object in `error` variable, so when the `error_tmp` got deleted, you still had the reference to the exception object using the `error` variable.